# Encountering 'namespace undefined' error when using a namespace with ts-node

Tags: typescript, namespaces, ts-node

I create a `helpers.ts` file like this:

```
//helpers.ts
namespace helpers {
  export function genDescArr(from: number, to: number): number[] {
    let arr: number[] = [];
    for (let i = from; i >= to; i--) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

and when using genDescArr function in other file like this:

```
//insert.ts
/// <reference path="./helpers.ts"/>
 const array = helpers.genDescArr(100, 1);
```

compile with `ts-node` and got error `ReferenceError: helpers is not defined`

I change `helpers.ts` to `helpers.d.ts` and use declare for helpers namespace but got same error!

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```